# Missing Completely at Random MCAR

Tags: random, missing

Many other stats packages have tests for MCAR but Mathematica doesn't seem to.

Have a I missed something?  If not what would a simple implementation in MMA look like.

(disclaimer I'm new to MCAR so forgive the lack of a concrete example)